# App rejected by Apple caused by using Google Maps SDK

Tags: ios, google-maps, app-store

I've been using GoogleMaps iOS SDK in my app for a while, everything goes fine when I submit to App Store.

But this time I got rejected by Apple, and they say I'm using non-public selector in my app.
The selector is called `imageWithName`

First, I use Xcode to search if there is any class using this method, result shows nothing.

Then, I use `grep -r imageWithName`, the result shows GoogleMaps is using the selector

[image: http://i.imgur.com/HAqWgvO.png]

I'm using CocoaPods to install GoogleMaps, and the version is `1.13.0`
Previous successful submission is using 1.13.0, too.
So I'm wondering if this is a bug caused by Apple or Google Maps.

I've filed a issue to Google's forum, and accepted by Google staff.
(https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9704)

Wondering if anyone facing same issue with me?

Screen shot of App Store reject

[image]

Comment: You've already gotten a response from Google, saying that it's a false positive and suggesting for you to add a `NOOP` (no operation) function or a dummy class that contains a `imageWithName` method.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. 
I'll keep this post in case anybody facing the same issue.

Comment: If this works for you, please post it as an answer and accept it to help others

Comment: Still doesn't work..trying to submit an appeal and DTS to Apple..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved the problem, reported this issue to Google Maps API Forum,
They've released a new version v1.13.2, this version works and approved by Apple app review team.

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal&groupby=&sort=&id=9704