# Is using GMSMap reason for rejection?

Tags: ios, gmsmapview

My app uses GMSMap to show some locations on map and users can open Yandex Navi, Google Maps app and also Apple maps to navigate selected poi. Only installed apps are listed to build route. Somehow my app is rejected. They send me the following message:

### Your app's location feature is not integrated with the built-in mapping functionality, which limits users to a third-party maps app.

Specifically, revise your app to give users the option to launch the native Apple Maps app from any tabs and/or hyperlink(s) in the third party map interface.

Next Steps

Please revise your app to give users the option to launch the native Apple Maps app.

What is the main problem? Is it related to using GMSMap in my app or is it related to triggering apps?

Comment: Are you launching Google maps via URL Scheme anywhere from your application?

Comment: @SahebRoy yes, related code is
`UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: "comgooglemaps://?saddr=&daddr=" + String(destLan) + "," + String(destLon) + "&directionsmode=driving")!)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am posting this answer to help people with the same problem. After making phone call, reviewer said that using only GMSMapView is the reason for rejection and MKMapView should be given as an option to show coordinates. I used only GMSMapView in my app and they rejected it just for that!  There is no written rule for this rejection. It is totally ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through some more problems as such app getting rejection for the reason you stated and many people have posted this scenario in Google forums [here](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal&groupby=&sort=&id=9704)

My opinion would be to update the GoogleMap SDK to the newest framework which is approved by the Apple team.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37313194/3755838) answer for further discussion on this

## EDIT

About the URL scheme have you added the respective URL Scheme in plist under the key `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>comgooglemaps</string>
    <string>comgooglemaps-x-callback</string>
</array>
```

And then having a condition like `canOpenURL` and then opening the URL scheme.

Comment: I have added related strings to info.plist. There are also some conditions to check `canOpenURL`. The version is GoogleMaps (2.1.1) and this version is the latest one.

Comment: Are you using any manager for these frameworks i.e Cocoapods or Carthage?